# A modal dialog box with some text, a drop down that takes values from an array and a button using Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, dialog

I'm just a beginner with Google Apps Script. I need help with a code that generates a dialog box with some text, a drop down that takes values from array named "arrayOfNames" and a button, clicking on this button would return the selected value from the drop down in the variable "tempString".

**file.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <p>Please select the name that matches: name3</p>
  <select id="names" text="Select a name" onload="fill()">
    <option selected disabled>Select a name</option>
    <?var options = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<arrayOfNames.length; i++){?>
      <option><?options[i]?></option>
    <?}?>
  </select><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="">OK</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Run test function', 'testFunction')
    .addToUi();
}
var ActiveSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Sheet1Sheet = ActiveSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var arrayOfNames = Sheet1Sheet.getRange(1, 1, 4).getDisplayValues();
var tempString = arrayOfNames[0][0];
function testFunction() {
  //"name1" will be initially stored in tempString.
  Browser.msgBox("The tempString value before selecting a name in the pop-up box is: " + tempString);
  /*
  a message box that 
  displays some text like : "Please select the name that matches: name3".
  Has a drop-down selection box that is populated with the names in arrayOfNames.
  returns the selected value into tempString.
  */
  
  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("file");
  for( var i=0; i<arrayOfNames.length; i++){
    widget.options[i] = arrayOfNames[i];
    var message = widget.evaluate.getContent();
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, "Select a name");
  //Browser.msgBox("The tempString value after selecting a name in the pop-up box is: " + tempString);
}
```

Comment: [why reinvent the wheel?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)

Comment: You should create and template first and then use evaluate on the template to get the htmloutput.  Evaluate is not a method of htmloutput it is a  method of htmlTemplate

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using Templated HTML to create a `<select>`.

**HTML_Test**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <p>Please select the name that matches: name3</p>
  <select id="names" text="Select a name">
    <option selected disabled>Select a name</option>
    <? for(var i=0; i<arrayOfNames.length; i++){ ?>
      <option><?= arrayOfNames[i] ?></option>
    <?}?>
  </select><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="">OK</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function showTest() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().map( row => row[0] ); // get the name from each row
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
  html.arrayOfNames = values;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Test");
}
```

The following is the modal dialog with the names from Column A of Sheet1:

[image]

Reference

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html_5)